# Sending push notification using Socket IO in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, socket.io

I am developing a spring boot application, with socket io server implementation to communicate with client. My intention is to send one push notification from server to client in a particular function. How do i make it possible. I need to trigger send event in a separate service class.

Socket IO implementation class

```
@Configuration
public class Socket {
    @Value("${socket.io.ip}")
    private String hostIP;

    @Value("${socket.io.port}")
    private int hostPort;

    @Bean
    public void setupSocketServer() {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.setHostname(hostIP);
        config.setPort(hostPort);
        SocketIOServer socketServer = new SocketIOServer(config);
        socketServer.addEventListener("chat", ChatObject.class, new DataListener<ChatObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onData(final SocketIOClient client, ChatObject data, final AckRequest ackRequest) {

                // check is ack requested by client,
                // but it's not required check
                if (ackRequest.isAckRequested()) {
                    // send ack response with data to client
                    ackRequest.sendAckData("client message was delivered to server!", "yeah!");
                }


                // send message back to client with ack callback WITH data
                ChatObject ackChatObjectData = new ChatObject(data.getUserName(), "message with ack data");
                client.sendEvent("chatResponse1", new AckCallback<String>(String.class) {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String result) {
                        System.out.println("ack from client: " + client.getSessionId() + " data: " + result);
                    }
                }, ackChatObjectData);
            }
        });

        socketServer.start();
    }
}
```

Service class

```
class userService{
 void sendnotification(msg){
 // need to  call sendEvent function here
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by using UUID of socket client. Created a socket client using UUID which is saved while connecting a new client to server. And reused it wherever I wanted.

```
SocketIOClient client = socketServer.getClient(uuid);
```